# What protocol do I use? Rtsp?

Tags: c#, java, streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm trying to build an ip camera app on a mobile device(android) that received input from camera and sends it straight to an endpoint server where everybody could track the camera's output. Problem is I haven't worked with this before and it was very hard for me since the beginning. Could anybody give me a clue what protocol do I use? The server side can be written in anything, I thought in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native for Android [RTSP](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). Very good example its [Spydroid](https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/)

Also not native fo Android [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) - the way to stream from android: [RTMP Client for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/) or not free [Aftek library](http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-RTMP-library.shtml).

And I think [HTTP Live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) - also possible, but I cann't found example.

Hope It's Help.